# Change color of DBGrid row

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tdbgrid

**how change latest rec color dbgrid?**

```
if (Sender as TDBGrid).DataSource.DataSet.RecNo = (Sender as TDBGrid)
  .DataSource.DataSet.RecordCount then
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color := $00C66F71;
end;
(Sender as TDBGrid).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `OnDrawColumnCell` property of `TDbGrid`

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if (Sender as TDBGrid).DataSource.DataSet.RecNo = (Sender as TDBGrid).DataSource.DataSet.RecordCount then
begin
  //change color of row    
  DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color:=$00C66F71;
  DBGrid1.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```

To change color of text use :

```
DBGrid1.Canvas.Font.Color:=clRed;
DBGrid1.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
```

In your code

```
Canvas.Brush.Color:=$00C66F71;
```

is `Canvas` of the `TForm`,  not `Canvas` of the `TDbgrid`